# A dynamically created button doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I've got this code to replace one button with another:

```
("#addEntry").replaceWith($('<button class="btn default add-entry" id="update">Update</button>'));
```

Chrome developer tools show such button is created. However, when I want to add an event handler, it just doesn't work!

```
$("#update").on("click", updateEntry);

function updateEntry () {
    alert("started");
};
```

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you do not have multiple `#update` elements in the page..

Comment: When do you add the event handler?  If it is not AFTER the #update button is created, then the event will not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).on("click", "#update", updateEntry);
```

Comment: @Rory maybe because I didn't really explain. Since other answers give better explanation, no point adding now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the button is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', '#update', updateEntry);
```

If possible, replace `document` here with the nearest static parent element **ID** or **class**, lets say `container` as *ID*. Then the code will be like:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#update', updateEntry);
```

This will attach your event to any button within the `#container` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You must use delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#update", updateEntry);
```

Take a look at [**Direct and delegated events**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I also don't know... But a vote up make much more than one down. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("body").on("click","#update", updateEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class not ID otherwise there are multiple Id in a page.
  Also try this way .

```
$("body").on("click",".update", updateEntry);

function updateEntry () {
    alert("started");
};
```

Note : (.update) in case of class